# Insert variables into oracle table with option

Tags: asp.net

l have two tables

table A 
name 
lastname 
tshirt-color

table B
tshirt_id
tshirt-color

in table A t shirt color is represented in form of the tshirt_id
taken from table_B. The user will not however enter the tshirt_id during an insert 
they will enter the actual color. l need the statement to look into table B and insert the 
tshirt_id where the user has entered the actual colour

so what l want to say is :
insert values into table A (name, lastname , tshirt_id) where tshirt_color = tshirt_id

Comment: First, I would suggest that you normalize your table.  Why do you have the same field(tshirt-color) in both tables?  This will cause what is know as update/delete anomalies.  You will do yourself a service if you familiarize yourself with database normalization (http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm).  Second, what have you tried?  Show us some code.  Thirdly, what database system are you using (access, oracle, mySql, ms sql)?

Comment: SORRY guys as you can tell lm new to this , l have tried all the earth has to give me and lm useing oracle. thank you l will read up on normalisation . thank you